# Get only polygons inside a bbox

Tags: python, polygon, geopandas, multi-polygon

I have a shapefile that has many polygons, here is an example:
[image]

Now, what I want to do is show the polygons that are around one particular location. So I don't have to show all the polygons.

So I began to try something, like creating a circle (we can also do with a rectangle), and try to limit/cut the polygons, or at least, find the only polygons in the circle.

```
import folium
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point
center_location = (48.8566, 2.3522)
m = folium.Map(location=center_location, zoom_start=12)
circle_radius = 5000
center_point = Point(center_location)
circle = center_point.buffer(circle_radius)
polygons_in_circle = gdf[gdf.geometry.intersects(circle)]
polygons_in_circle
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Depending on what you need, you can also filter already when reading the file using the `bbox` parameter: `df = geopandas.read_file("nybb.shp", bbox=(0, 0, 10, 20))`. If your file has a spatial index this will also be relatively fast.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
import geopandas as gpd

df = gpd.read_file(r"C:\GIS\data\testdata\zy_riks_4326.shp")
center = (64.77626, 14.51378)

#Reproject the df to a projected crs with units in meters, so the units make sense. Or the radius will be in degrees
df = df.to_crs(3006) #Im in Sweden so I pick 3006. You should choose another local one.

#Select by a rectangle
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = 465000,490000,7170000,7200000
rectframe = df.cx[xmin:xmax, ymin:ymax]

#Select by a circle
radius = 10000
circle = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(x=[center[1]], y=center[0]), crs=4326).to_crs(3006)
circle.geometry= circle.geometry.buffer(radius)
circleframe = gpd.sjoin(df, circle, how="inner") #If you want to clip by the circle you can use gpd.overlay

base = df.plot(color="gray")
rectframe.plot(ax=base, color="red")
circleframe.plot(ax=base, color="blue")
```

[image]